# How to download file rather than HTML with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Okay so I decided I'd like a program to download osu maps based on the map number(for lack of a better term). After doing some testing with the links to understand the redirecting, I got a program which gets to the `.../download` page - when I got to said page, the map will download. However, when trying to download it via requests, I get HTML.

```py
    def grab(self, identifier=None):
        if not identifier:
            print("Missing Argument: 'identifier'")
            return
        mapLink = f"https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmaps/{identifier}"
        dl = requests.get(mapLink, allow_redirects=True)
        if not dl:
            print("Error: map not found!")
            return
        mapLink2 = dl.url 
        mapLink2 = f"https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/{self.parseLink(mapLink2)}/download"
        dl = requests.get(mapLink2)

        with open(f"{identifier}.osz", "wb") as f:
            f.write(dl.content)
```

And, in case it is necessary, here is `self.parseLink`:

```py
    def parseLink(self, mapLink=None):
        if not mapLink:
            return None
        id = mapLink.replace("https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/","")
        id = id.split("#")
        return id[0]
```

Ideally, when I open the file at the end of `grab()`, it should save a usable `.osz` file - one which is NOT html, and can be dragged into the actual game and used. Of course, this is still extremely early in my testing, and I will figure out a way to make the filename the song name for convenience.

edit: example of an `identifier` is: `OsuMaps().grab("1385415")` in case you wanted to test

Comment: What does the HTML say? You must not be setting the `Referer`, `User-Agent`, or other expected headers so you are tripping the anti-hot-link/robot protection.

Comment: Open your browser's developer console and switch to Network tab, go to a download url and let the download start. Find the request that initiated the download and use it with `requests` library

Comment: It seems you need to be first logged into the site prior to download anything. I suggest to look at `requests.session()`

Comment: You should also check whether what you're doing is legal. Just because something is on the internet it doesn't mean you are allowed to write a script to fetch it. I suggest reading their terms and conditions, and contacting their customer support. If they want people to download their maps this way, they might have an API that is designed to use in scripts rather than scraping their website.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'd completely forgot about that - I will check it out now!

Comment: Seems like they do have an API: https://github.com/ppy/osu-api/wiki

Comment: @vekerdyb I'm sure it's legal - I've seen multiple other people do similar projects and post it on the forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very quick way to get around:

- Needing to be logged in
- Needing a specific element

This workaround comes in the form of `https://bloodcat.com/osu/` - to get a download link directly to a map, all you need is: `https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/<beatmap set number>`.

Here is an example:

```py
id = "653534" # this map is ILY - Panda Eyes 
mapLink = f"https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/{id}" # adds id to the link
dl = requests.get(mapLink)
if len(dl.content) > 330: # see below for explanation
    with open(f"{lines[i].rstrip()}.osz", "wb") as f:
    f.write(dl.content)
else:
    print("Map doesn't exist")
```

The line `if len(dl.conetent) > 330` is my workaround to a link not working. `.osz` files can contain thousands upon thousands of lines of unknown characters, whereas the site's "not found" page has less that 330 lines - we can use this to check if the file is too short to be a beatmap or not.

That's all! Feel free to use the code if you'd like.